# The GPS on my Galaxy Note IV is often wrong

Tags: gps, samsung-galaxy-note, samsung-galaxy-note-4, gps-tracking

While I'm at work the GPS location on my Galaxy Note IV is very poor, taking a long time to pinpoint a location, and often being off by a few streets when it does.

I have less issues while in a densely populated zone.

I understand why that is, the GPS itself doesn't get a strong signal from the satellites, so the phone uses celltowers or wifi access points to guess my location to the best of its abilities, and since there aren't a lot of those around me its guess is wrong.

My question is : Is there a way to fix this situation ? Can I indicate to Google that my location is wrong, or configure my phone to adjust for that error ?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Since there isn't anything technically wrong with the gps in your phone and it's just the location of where you are that throws it off, the best thing to do is just go outside and see if the signal is stronger from outside the building or deal with it. 
Google maps doesn't currently have any features that allow users to correct their location. You can type it in the search bar if you're trying to get from your current location to another but it won't exactly "***stick***".

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can send [feedback from within Google Maps](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094045?rd=2&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1):

> 1. Open the Google Maps app maps.
> 2. Touch the Menu .
> 3. Touch Send feedback > Send app feedback.
>
> Note: If you want to send feedback about the blue dot that shows your location, touch Report location issues.